# Add member counter to bot activity discord.js v.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to do that but it isn't working. How can I resolve this?
I want that the activiy is the current member Count (refreshing every 5 minutes(or when its possible everytime a member joined))

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    async execute(client) {

        setInterval(() => {
            let membersCount = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

        }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
        const options = [
            {
                type: ActivityType.Playing,
                text: `mit [${membersCount} usern]`,
                status: "online"
            }
        ];
        await client.user.setPrecence({
            activities: [{
                name: [options].text,
                type: [options].type
                },
            ],
            status: [options].status
        }).catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is just the positioning of the update function. What is happening right now is that, every five minutes, the `setInterval()` runs and updates the `memberCount` variable. But, the `await client.user.setPresence()` only runs one time when the `async execute()` function was first called . So to fix your code, you would just have to move the `options` variable and `await client.user.setPresence()` to inside the `setInterval()` function. Your fixed code would look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    async execute(client) {

        setInterval(() => {
            let membersCount = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
            const options = [
                {
                    type: ActivityType.Playing,
                    text: `mit [${membersCount} usern]`,
                    status: "online"
                }
            ];
            await client.user.setPrecence({
                activities: [{
                    name: options[0].text,
                    type: options[0].type
                }],
                status: options[0].status
            }).catch(console.error);
        }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
    }
}
```